# How to install ruby 1.8.7 on ubuntu 12.04 with rvm?

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I'm working with a legacy rails system. I need a copy of ruby 1.8.7
I've just been given a new computer at work (finally) and it has ubuntu 12.04

Unfortunately I've just discovered that the rvm-rubies available for my system do not contain 1.8.7 (see list below)

**How can I install ruby 1.8.7?
Is there another source that I can point to that will work?**

Please note: I did not use apt-get to install rvm, that is not the problem

This is the list of available rubies:

```
# Rubies available for 'ubuntu/12.04/x86_64':

   ruby-1.9.3-p194
   ruby-1.9.3-p286
   ruby-1.9.3-p327
   ruby-1.9.3-p362
   ruby-1.9.3-p374
   ruby-1.9.3-p392
   ruby-1.9.3-p429
   ruby-1.9.3-p448
   ruby-2.0.0-p0
   ruby-2.0.0-p195
   ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

**Edit:**

Just so you know, here's the output of some of the simpler rvm commands:

```
triton:[~]% rvm list  

rvm rubies

# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

And rvm install gives this message (which make sit clear there is no version of 1.8.7 in the standard repository).

```
triton:[~]% rvm install 1.8.7
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p374.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
You requested building with 'gcc-4.4' but it is not in your path.
```

Comment: My Ubuntu 12.08 has `ruby1.8` in `apt`. It is most likely unavailable in rvm since it has been phased out. EDIT: I have rubies from 1.8.6 in rvm available for installation...

Comment: I didn't install via apt. It's not looking in the apt-sources, but in the rvm sources. However - yes :) it's not available in rvm. I'm just wondering if there's another way to install with rvm - if I can point it at, say, the 10.04 rvm source (or whatever - as long as it has 1.8.7)

Comment: You can remove rvm and install ruby 1.8.7p374 from source code from here: ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/

Comment: Have you tried `rvm  install ruby-1.8.7` ?

Comment: I don't wish to remove rvm - I also need 1.9.X for the upgrade process...

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I just meant if you can't find it in rvm (which is weird, because I can), you can still get it from apt.

Comment: @Amadan - thanks - that'll be my fallback strategy ;)

Comment: Well, you can install 1.8.7 from source code and switch to it by `rvm use system` and then back to 1.9.x as usual.

Comment: Also, you can check if you have REE 1.8.7 available; it should be compatible AFAIK, just a bit more optimised for certain scenarios.

Comment: "And rvm install gives this message (which make sit clear there is no version of 1.8.7 in the standard repository)." That didn't make it clear that there is no version of 1.8.7, just no binaries of that version.  But it DOES make clear that you are missing a compiler called gcc.4-4

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> To install a specific tagged version of ruby from the repository we
>   specify -t(tag name).

It then goes on to talk about branches...

Repository Branches (MRI)

To install a specific branch version of ruby from the repository we specify --branch (branch name). Named rubies can help avoid clashes.

```
$ rvm install ruby-head -n zombie --branch ruby_1_8 && rvm ruby-head-zombie
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.8dev (2012-05-21) [i386-darwin10.8.0]
$ rvm install ruby-head -n newborn && rvm ruby-head-newborn
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0dev (2012-06-03 trunk 35876) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

You'll find a list of all valid branches in the ruby repository: http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/

You have access to much more than what is shown.

```
ruby_1_3/
ruby_1_4/
ruby_1_6/
ruby_1_8/
ruby_1_8_5/
ruby_1_8_6/
ruby_1_8_7/
ruby_1_9_1/
ruby_1_9_2/
ruby_1_9_3/
ruby_2_0_0/
```

More hints on the [RVM official website](http://rvm.io/rubies/installing)

Also, for additional help, the IRC Chat room on freenode.net is awesome!

Comment: Ok, I'm unsure what the zombie stuff is all about - and (like a sensible person) I'm loathe to just run commands I don't recognise ;) can you explain what the various parts of the commands you have above? Many thanks :)

Comment: I read that bit in the RVM website - but it doesn't explain: a) what it means by a branch b) whether or not they will run happily on any machine (I was concerned because the standard repo is marked for 64bit... so I don't want to go loading rubies that will only run on 32 bits, or on a different architecture by specifying the wrong branch)

Comment: The commands `rvm list` and `rvm list known` will show what can be installed.  The information starts to talk about how to install Rubies that you can compile and store in a repository of your choosing.  The 64 bit etc is not really relevant for a moving target such as name, they repository could just as well hold 32 bit.  It is just flexible that way.  The zombie stuff is simply by name, as he states.

Answer (score 0):

what you have presented is output from `rvm list remote` - which list binary (already compiled) rubies for your system, to see more possible choices of version run `rvm list` which will include `1.8.7`:

```
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p448]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p195
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p247]
[ruby-]2.0.0-head
ruby-head
```

and it continues with number of other ruby distributions.

If not sure you can always just run:

```
rvm install 1.8.7
```

RVM does all kind of detections and will most likely know what to do with specified version.

Comment: rvm list  

rvm rubies


# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.

Comment: rvm install 1.8.7
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p374.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
You requested building with 'gcc-4.4' but it is not in your path.

Comment: AFAICS "rvm list" lists the rubies currently available on your machine... there are currently none on my machine..
"rvm install" gives exactly the error I already discussed - because the repository doesn't have 1.8.7

Comment: ie I've already tried that and it does not know what to do with the specified version - that's why I'm here asking the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I figured it out.

The important clue was in the last line of the result for rvm install:

```
You requested building with 'gcc-4.4' but it is not in your path.
```

I had gcc version 4.6 but my .zshrc (copied from my previous computer) was pointing at this older version.

Because of this, rvm thought I didn't have a c-compiler. Which means that rvm wasn't able to install any rubies from source - only pre-compiled rubies - which means it was restricted to only those already pre-compiled for my platform (ie 64-bit ubuntu 12.04)

When I fixed the gcc line in my .zshrc - rvm was able to figure out how to install+compile source-code rubies - including v1.8.7